# Input user defined values inside multiple cells using vba

Tags: vba

I have to manipulate range of cells in excel using VB. Can I do it in the following manner ?

```
Range("a1:b5")=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I've never seen that syntax. One thing you *can* do is something like:

```
For Row = 1 To 5
    Range("a" + CStr(Row)).Value = Row
    Range("b" + CStr(Row)).Value = (Row + 5) Mod 10
Next Row
```

assuming that you want it set up thus:

```
    A  B
  +------
1 | 1  6
2 | 2  7
3 | 3  8
4 | 4  9
5 | 5  0
```

You *may* need to use `Mid(CStr(Row),2)` - I can't remember off the top of my head if `Cstr` gives you a leading space for non-negative numbers.

Comment: Can do with `Range("a" & Row).Value`